# What is the best way to say that something was done in teamwork?

Tags: business-language, expression-choice

In my resume, I'm describing several projects I've worked on in the past. Most
of them were done in teamwork. What is the best way to say this?

Examples:

Together with XY, I built ... OR

In collaboration with XY, I built ... OR

XY and I built ...

Are the first two examples grammatically correct? I'm unsure since first I state that something has been done in collaboration with a second person, but then I use "I built ...".

Comment: Employers really want to understand what parts ***you*** did yourself.  When you say I was on a team that did X it could be the case that you were a slacker and let the rest of the team do it all.  So mention the team but then call out specifically what you contributed.  "as a member of a team developing X, I produced Y"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very few major projects that do not require other players. Why not focus on your role?

> I was the principal author of three chapters in the technical manual for . . .
>
> I was the senior draftsman for the escape hatch on Space Shuttle 3  . . .

That there were others involved is obvious, and your skills and responsibility is highlighted.

Comment: +1 but <nitpick> principal author </nitpick>

Comment: A good nit. I routinely ask myself "which" on this and other homonyms, but slipped this time. Thanks. This is a tough crowd and I want to put my best face forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have written profiles and curriculum vitae for many people.

So far, the practice (“practice” is the noun, “practise” the verb - I mean noun here *wink ) is:

Worked in collaboration with (XY) as a/an (your designation)

'in collaboration' sounds perfect! rather 'team'. No matter how big the team is, team gives an impression of 'something small'. The same difference when you say, Chocolate was for £0.99 rather it was for 1 penny less for £1. Difference!

Use "in collaboration with" but also mention your role because as Jim said employers would be more interested in knowing what 'you did' rather what 'you all did'.

Best of luck! :)